# JPA @OneToMany: Returning only some values from map in a query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to run a JPA query to return only specific fields from my entity, rather than the entire entity (for performance reasons).

Within this entity is this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, mappedBy = "helper", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "year")
public Map<Integer, DutyHistory> getDutyHistoryList() {
    return dutyHistoryList;
}
```

I'd like, within my query, to return multiple values from this map e.g. fields from the DutyHistory object for the last 3 years.

My question is, what's the query syntax for this? I'm mapping the returned values to a POJO as below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.castlemon.helpers.dto.ReportHelper(h.helperId, h.firstName, h.secondName"
            + ", h.sex, h.service, h.dateOfBirth, h.schoolGroup, h.orientationRequired, h.notes as adminNotes "
            + ", h.primaryDuty.dutyName as primaryDuty, h.secondDuty, h.secondaryDuty.dutyName as secondaryDuty "            
            + " WHERE h.travelling = 1")
    public List<ReportHelper> getTravellingHelperDetails();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create another query with your "year" parameter

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.castlemon.helpers.dto.ReportHelper(h.helperId, h.firstName, h.secondName"
        + ", h.sex, h.service, h.dateOfBirth, h.schoolGroup, h.orientationRequired, h.notes as adminNotes "
        + ", h.primaryDuty.dutyName as primaryDuty, h.secondDuty, h.secondaryDuty.dutyName as secondaryDuty "            
        + " WHERE h.travelling = 1 AND h.year >= :yearLimit")
public List<ReportHelper> getTravellingHelperDetailsUntilYear(String yearLimit);
```

Comment: Year isn't a field on the Helper object, it's on the DutyHistory object. And I'm wondering how to represent this as discrete fields in the select statement.

Comment: So I guess the projection on the date should be done on the DutyHistory object. How it is related to your Helper is up to your model : join, left join...

Comment: It would be a left join.

Comment: So you'll have something like this : "select new Helper(h.id, h.toto) from Helper h left join h.dutyHistory d where d.year >= :year"

Comment: @uncleBounty In this case author can get multiple records for one helper, because of OneToMany relation. It may be better to use something like "select new Helper(...) from Helper h where exists(select d from DutyHistory d where d.helper = h.helperId and d.year>=:year)"